# Phonegap version 3 phonegap.js not found

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have created a project in phonegap using version 3:

```
phonegap create -n SexDiaries -i co.uk.couplesdiaries
```

But when opening the `index.html` I get a network error that `phonegap.js` cannot be found, 404.

Why would they request a file that doesn't exist from the default build?

Where can I find this file?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting app ;)

Comment: Its the best app in the world :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The phonegap.js is not in the root for example:

```
 projectname/www/phonegap.js
```

As you would expect, instead you need to first create a platform for the app to be build on, for example build the android platform with:

```
phonegap build android
```

Then, go inside the folder created:

```
platforms/android/assets/www
```

and then you'll see phonegap.js and all other things. It's very poorly documented :)

Comment: I am very confused with PhoneGap.  If you have a separate www folder for each "build", then where is the benefit?  I am still having to maintain several different code bases, one for each arch type.  Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: no no :) the separate game bases are for only trouble shooting, you use adobe to compile from one repo. You'll want to use this: https://build.phonegap.com/ I put everything on github and pull that way, but you can upload a zip file i believe

Comment: I was trying to do my dev/test out of the base www folder using Ripple.  Is there some way to do that with the phonegap.js missing, or do I not need it?

Comment: yep, you'll need that unfortunatly. SO you couldn't get the steps i outlined working?

Comment: Well, I can run the build command, which generates a platform, but then I have to do development in that tool (in my case iOS, so XCode) and then move all the code changes backwards into the base www folder.  I was hoping just to use Ripple to do all the initial dev, using python's SimpleHttpServer host the files local, and then run the build just to verify.  I think part of the problem is that I don't quite have my head wrapped around the development process/workflow with PhoneGap, nor the proper tools to use at each step.  I find the docs on the PG site to be lacking.

Comment: no no, you leave it in the folder where it is built, otherwise the apple app won't know what to compile from. Indeed the documentation is crap :) new things always are :p Leave it in there, build your app like you say and then zip it all up at the www and upload to build.phonegap.com and it will give you each of the apps complied for you.

Comment: I'm not sure quite how I got there, but I didn't have `phonegap.js` in this folder; I had `cordova.js`.  I copied this and renamed it to `phonegap.js` and that seems to have worked

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding a new answer because this SO post keeps coming up everytime I searched for "phonegap.js missing":

If you follow several guides out there you might see a reference to `cordova build [platform]`. With PhoneGap ***do not*** do this. Instead this is correct:

```
phonegap build [platform]
```

Then visit your `platforms/[platform]` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a mobile app using html+css+jQuery mobile and i am building it using the  [phonegap web build service](https://build.phonegap.com/). The version of phonegap i am working on is 3.1.0.

I was trying to find how to use the [Phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/index.html) on my mobile application and how to call the cordova methods (ex notification.alert). The solution to this is to just add the

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

inside the head of your index.html document. The Phonegap builder will find and include the correct cordova.js file for each build (Android, Win phone, iOS). If you will use the application on web then this script tag will always throw a 404 HTTP code.

Finally, the [ondeviceready event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) is essential to any application. See the Full Example.